# data given in the Ajax is not reaching in the views.py file and hence alert function is not working

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, httpresponse

I tried to reset password using Ajax in Django.For that, firstly I took email id from input box using a function and send it to views.py file using Ajax.In views.py file,there is a code for receiving email-id using GET method and check whether the email-id is available or not in the table.If available send the email-id back to html file using HttpResponse and display it using alert function.But it does not work properly.Can anyone suggest a solution for this.

HTML file :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    {% load static %}
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Index Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'styles/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script>
        function getpass(){
            let username=$("#uname").val()
            $.ajax({
                url : "{% url 'passwordreset' %}",
                type : "GET",
                data : {username : username},

                success :function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <section class="sflog" id="sflog">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" id="std">
                    <form method="GET" action="">
                        {%csrf_token%}
                        <center>
                            <h3>Password <span>Reset</span></h3><br><br>
                        </center>
                        <div id="result"></div>
                        <label style="color:white;padding-left:13%;">Enter Your Username</label>
                         <center>
                             <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br>
                         </center>
                         <button type="submit" style="margin-left:12%;" onclick="getpass()" name="login">Submit</button><br><br><br><br>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('User/Forgot_Password',views.user_forgot_password,name="ufpassword"),
    path('User/Forgot_Password/Reset',views.user_forgot_password_reset,name="passwordreset"),
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from user.models import clientlogin
from django.http import HttpResponse

def user_forgot_password(request):
    return render(request,"forgot_password.html")

def user_forgot_password_reset(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        un = request.GET.get('username')
        print(un)
        try:
            user = get_object_or_404(clientlogin, Username=un)
            return HttpResponse(user.Username)
        except:
            return HttpResponse("No user registered with this Email ID")

    else:
        return render(request, "forgot_password.html")
```

Comment: You need to include the jquery url before using it in your code, preferrably in the head section

Comment: Your issue is that the form is being submitted and your `onclick` handler does not do anything because the submit reloads the page. You need to add an event handler for the form submit event and then call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting

Answer (score 0):

First change the order in urls

```
urlpatterns=[
 path('User/Forgot_Password',views.user_forgot_password,name="ufpassword"), 
path('User/Forgot_Password/Reset',views.user_forgot_password_reset,name="passwordreset")
 ]
```

Because when request arrives, it will match the first always so either edit it to be

```
re_path('User/Forgot_Password$',views.user_forgot_password,name="ufpassword")
```

This way your reset URL won't match the forget password.

As some said put JQuery before $ sign.